# Sanic 22.6 websocket protocol - how to check if a websocket is open?

Tags: sanic

When connecting to a sanic websocket, a 'WebsocketImplProtocol' is returned (on the server handler).  This can be used to send and recv.  However how can we check the websocket state? (i.e. whether it is closed/open/closing etc.). I think that this was possible in earlier versions of Sanic, but not now (Sanic 22.6)

Comment: The handler task will be canceled when it is closed

Comment: @AdamHopkins True, but this doesn't enable other threads to tell whether the websocket is usable.

Comment: Like what? Sounds like something you'd need to track on your own. The ws is bound to the task